# Improve speed of android app

Tags: android

In my android program, I have 3 functions that will be continuously repeated until the user exits the app. Currently, it is able to update a value(position) **every second**.

I was wondering if having lots of if else condition in one of the function will slow down the performance of my app i.e. it might take way longer than a second for the updates to kick in.

Note that 2 of the if else function will execute only **once**. All the if-else function have very little code in it. Below is the code

```
public void positionUpdated(Coordinate userPosition, int accuracy) {

    // GETS EXECUTED ONCE //
    if(nameList.size() == 0) {nameList = indoorsFragment.getZones();}
    if(end == null) {
        for(int i=0 ; i < nameList.size() ; i++) if(nameList.get(i).equals(name)) end = nameList.get(i).getZonePoints().get(0);
    }
    // GETS EXECUTED ONCE //

    if(Math.abs(userPosition.x - end.x) >500) {Toast.makeText(this,"WALK " + Math.abs(end.x - userPosition.x)/1000 + " Meters" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();return;}

    if(turn) {
        if ((userPosition.y - end.y) < 0) {Toast.makeText(this, "STOP AND TURN RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();turn=false;return;}
        if ((userPosition.y - end.y) > 0) {Toast.makeText(this, "STOP AND TURN LEFT" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();turn=false;return;}
    }

    if((Math.abs(userPosition.y - end.y) < 500)) Toast.makeText(this, "WALK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Hope to receive some feedback regarding this , thanks
Haziq

Comment: This is a non-issue. You shouldn't be thinking about this. Especially about if-statements. Focus more on intensive work like iterations. For-loops, etc. 

I think you shouldn't worry unless you actually see your app lagging.

Comment: A 1hz is a really slow intervall and is, as @David said a non-issue. As Donald Knuth put it "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Answer (score 1):

The number of statements doesn't really matter, in fact they're executed in fractions of nanoseconds. what matters is if you have many nested loops or recursions.

If you don't want much work to be done in the foreground thread, use an `AsyncTask` or `Runnable` then update the UI in the main thread.